# VB.NET Custom class list of array

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently trying to recreate an enigma machine in vb.net as good practice.
I'm trying to create a custom class for the rotors.

The rotors should contain as integer Shift which counts the number of shifts that it went through so if it reaches 26 the other rotor shifts.

Also a list or array of 26 lines which each contains 26 plugs 
example of the configuration of a rotor:

```
18 16 0 11 23 4 9 19 8 1 17 13 2 24 22 6 15 21 12 7 14 20 5 10 25 3
19 13 9 0 2 17 12 24 4 14 15 8 7 5 21 18 1 6 25 23 20 3 11 22 10 16
18 13 23 5 6 16 2 25 11 1 20 17 4 10 14 0 19 3 8 15 22 9 12 21 7 24
25 10 17 21 3 12 16 4 19 20 6 9 8 13 7 18 1 15 14 2 23 22 11 5 24 0
18 23 7 12 17 24 25 5 20 8 0 15 14 21 1 3 9 13 22 19 2 4 10 6 11 16
7 23 0 24 3 25 10 2 15 19 16 14 17 9 11 13 5 20 8 1 21 6 18 12 22 4
11 12 7 14 24 0 19 2 10 8 22 17 4 15 5 13 3 16 21 6 9 25 18 1 20 23
11 5 14 7 12 6 15 25 20 23 18 21 9 19 17 8 4 1 22 2 16 10 0 13 3 24
7 19 10 25 15 13 12 14 4 8 21 17 0 22 11 24 18 2 9 1 20 5 3 16 23 6
19 23 1 21 0 15 10 2 7 4 22 12 14 9 17 20 11 8 18 13 5 6 16 3 25 24
19 13 14 12 6 23 18 7 9 17 22 8 15 1 24 5 10 20 16 11 2 21 0 3 25 4
4 1 5 3 10 13 24 25 21 18 16 6 20 11 17 19 7 14 0 23 9 15 2 12 22 8
19 18 22 10 17 6 20 13 2 12 14 15 24 1 11 9 8 3 5 4 7 25 0 16 21 23
16 13 14 1 8 11 9 25 24 3 2 4 0 5 22 18 19 7 17 15 23 20 6 10 12 21
2 15 20 0 16 17 1 24 8 23 14 21 3 4 11 19 9 5 6 22 7 12 18 25 10 13
22 10 17 9 4 20 24 2 13 25 8 21 23 0 19 7 11 5 15 1 16 3 14 12 6 18
5 14 0 10 21 9 3 25 13 1 4 18 8 17 22 2 20 24 15 19 23 16 7 11 12 6
15 1 13 2 19 7 9 16 11 10 17 14 4 25 6 24 0 23 22 21 8 20 5 12 18 3
12 8 20 6 11 3 10 23 21 14 13 7 0 22 19 4 16 2 5 15 9 17 1 18 24 25
4 8 25 5 1 12 10 22 9 24 14 19 2 0 6 20 17 3 23 15 13 11 21 16 18 7
11 21 5 6 16 19 13 20 23 10 18 14 3 8 15 24 0 25 4 22 12 7 1 17 2 9
5 24 19 23 17 18 0 11 2 20 14 1 25 22 9 6 15 7 10 13 8 12 16 3 4 21
1 11 8 13 3 22 14 19 4 6 5 15 24 9 21 23 7 0 2 12 25 10 16 17 20 18
18 3 19 16 10 24 23 1 22 17 20 9 7 14 2 21 5 8 0 11 13 4 15 25 12 6
5 11 7 0 8 2 13 17 23 16 9 10 20 12 19 3 25 24 18 21 14 22 15 6 4 1
10 2 3 22 16 6 15 19 1 20 18 24 13 5 8 23 21 7 14 17 9 11 25 12 4 0
```

For now i have tried this but it doesnt seem to work very well:

```
Public Class Rotor

    Public Property lines As New List(Of Liner)()
    Public Property shift As Integer
    Public Structure Liner
        Public Property plug() As Integer()
    End Structure
End Class
```

And my configuration loader:

```
Public Sub ConfigRotor(ByVal RotorConf As Rotor, ByVal PathConf As String)
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines(PathConf)
        Dim y As Integer = 0
        For Each strr As String In line.Split(" ")
            RotorConf.lines(i).plug(y)
            y = y+1
        Next

        i = i + 1
        If i > 26 Then
            MsgBox("Configuration file not supported")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Would you see a more optimized way you could refer me to to easily handle this?

Comment: This may be more suitable for CodeReview?

Comment: "y = +1"  ? that'll put 1 inside y all the time. I don't know how you initialize your array, either... saying "doesnt seem to work very well" isn't very clear. what doesn't work?

Comment: @the_lotus sorry typo mistake haha corrected it

Comment: @Crimson-Med how can you make a typo? does that mean you didn't just copy/paste your code?

Comment: @the_lotus i did just that i had added that line after copy pasting

Comment: @Crimson-Med you're not doing anything with strr, and this line seems to be doing nothing "RotorConf.lines(i).plug(y)". Also, structure are passed by value, not reference.

Comment: @the_lotus yeah i figure the way i construct my class is not accurate but im a bit new to lists so no idea how i could define a list (representing the 26 lines of the rotor) each containing an array (representing the 26 plugs) in a clean and efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the correct way to declare your class is like this:

```
Public Class Rotor

    Public Property lines As New List(Of Liner)
    Public Property shift As Integer
    Public Structure Liner
        Public Property plug As Integer()
    End Structure
End Class
```

To get a eficiente code, I suggest you to change your file type from text to binary. It is easier and faster to read and manipulate a byte array and convert it to an int array than anything you could do with a string array.

I will assume that your file is binary and that you have stored into it the exact amount of bytes you need (26 x 26 = 676 bytes). The code would be like this:

```
Public Sub ConfigRotor(ByVal RotorConf As Rotor, ByVal PathConf As String)
    Dim myArray() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(PathConf)

    If (myArray.Length <> 676) Then
        MsgBox("Configuration file not supported")
    Else
        RotorConf.lines.Clear()
        For pos As Integer = 0 To myArray.Length - 1 Step 26
            Dim line As New Rotor.Liner
            Dim newPlug(25) As Integer
            line.plug = newPlug
            Array.Copy(myArray, pos, line.plug, 0, 26)
            RotorConf.lines.Add(line)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Easy, fast and clean.
The total amount of time for running this code is less than 1ms (depending on the speed of your ard drive).

Answer (score 0):

Well since no one was available to help I did something its really ugly but it works. If anyone for future refference is interested I declared two structures:

```
Public Structure rotori
    Dim lines() As liner
    Public shift As Integer
End Structure

Public Structure liner
    Public plugs() As Integer
End Structure
```

Then I used ReDim on app launch like this:

```
Dim Rotor1 As New rotori
ReDim Rotor1.lines(25)
For b As Integer = 0 To 25
     ReDim Rotor1.lines(b).plugs(25)
Next
```